# Page 2 of “Pine Editor” tab?

Tags: pine-script

Silly question, but I can’t figure it out.
The “top page” of the pine editor tab (the code page) runs down to the bottom of the screen, because of this, I can’t see where it tells you what your errors are. It doesn’t drag and I don’t see how to resize it.

Thanks for your time!

Ben

Answer (score 1):

To display the console with error messages, use the keys  Ctrl + `

Comment: Nice! :) Didn't know that.

Comment: Ctr; + What?.... what key is `?

Comment: @Camilo This may depend on the localization of your keyboard. I have the ` key located on the same button with ~. Pay attention to the button to the left of button `1`.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't show by default.
It'll automatically pop up when you try to save a script that contains an error.
Once it's visible, you can resize or minimize it.
Once minimized, it won't show again until the next time you try to save an error.

**Edit 1**
You can also right-click the line number area to bring up the `Show Console` context menu.

[image: Right-click for context menu]